# Counter function for notifications works not as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers, notifications

I have table with notifications (category_id, user_id, seen) and counter table: notifications_counter (user_id, unread)

When user has new notification (it inserts in notification table with seen=false), unread value for his guid in notifications_counter table must increment.
When user mark notification as seen (notifications.seen=true), it must be decremented.

It works if user marks 1 notification as seen. But if he marks many (by category_id), notifications_counter.unread decrements, but not as it should - the value remains bigger than it should have been (for example, it was 2000, user marks notifications as seen by category_id (600 notifications marked) and it can became 1900 (must be 1400)).

function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notifications.notify_seen_upd()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
  begin 
      if new.seen = true and old.seen = false then 
        update notifications.notifications_counter 
            set unread = 
                (select unread
                from notifications.notifications_counter 
                where notifications_counter.user_id = new.user_id) - 1
            where notifications_counter.user_id = new.user_id;
      end if;
      if new.seen = false and old.seen = true then
        update notifications.notifications_counter 
        set unread =
            (select unread
                from notifications.notifications_counter 
                where notifications_counter.user_id = new.user_id) + 1
            where notifications_counter.user_id = new.user_id;
      end if;
  return new;        
  end;
$function$
;
```

trigger :

```
create trigger z_notifications_upd after
update
    on
    notifications.notifications for each row execute function notifications.notify_seen_upd();
```

I've tried before trigger, the result is the same

Example of script that invokes the trigger:

```
UPDATE notifications.notifications AS t SET seen = true
WHERE (t.user_id = '6a16ca48-c215-4e9f-9d0f-cb78a0915192' and t.category_id = 1)
```

What can cause this trouble?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Show the code that invokes the trigger.

Comment: Is "seen" possibly null?

Comment: No, "seen" can be true or false, column is 'not null'

Answer (score 1):

This logic seems so complicated.  Does this keep the counter up-to-date?

```
update notifications.notifications_counter nc
    set unread = nc.unread +
                 (case when new.seen and not old.seen then -1
                       when not new.seen and old.seen then 1
                       else 0
                  end)
    where nc.user_id = new.user_id and
          new.seen <> old.seen;
```

Comment: I like your function way more than mine, thanks! But result is the same...

Answer (score 1):

I am going to suggest an alternative approach. Do not try keeping a running total, it is more trouble than it worth. Instead get rid of the notifications_counter table. This also gets rid of the trigger and corresponding determination of state change. Now create a VIEW notifications_counter. You can now just count seen vs not seen providing the same and additional information, with much less work. See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4a645198d435cd1fff91d50329cbeaef).

```
create view notifications_counter as
   select user_id 
        , count(*) as total 
        , count(*) filter (where seen)  as read
        , count(*) filter (where not seen)  as unread
     from user_notifications 
    group by user_id ;
```

Also it has the advantage that you need not worry about a notification being deleted.

Comment: Thank you, but count is too expensive operation, I have many notifications it can be increased by 12000 per day for user...

Comment: OK, but make sure you handle delete. In that case new.seen will be NULL. And the inevitable race conditions, and locks; which could slow the entire system down not just querying the counts.